# React: Slide a div component out the div and bring another one in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I am creating a signin page where the user is brought to a page where they FIRST enter their username, then they click next and a fluid slide animation occurs and the password field comes in from the right. I have the separate components coded already. the animation itself works but this is the ending result[enter image description here][1]

BEFORE NEXT CLICK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bj3x.png

AFTER NEXT CLICK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHD0V.png

It brings it out of the page.

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useRef} from 'react'
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'
import PageTransition from '../components/PageTransition'

const Auth = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const pageComponents = [
        <>
        <div>
            <div className="flex inline-block">
                <img src={require("../images/Logo.jpg")} alt="logo" className=" w-12 h-12 mb-4" />
                <h1 className="text-primary font-CreteRoundRegular text-4xl ml-2 mt-1 ">TEST</h1>
            </div>

            <div className="flex flex-col mr-auto w-full">
                <p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-xl text-primary mt-2">Sign In</p>
                <input id="input-username" type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone" className="border-b-2 py-2 w-full border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-500 mb-4 mt-2" />
            </div>

            <div className="flex inline-block">
                <p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-sm text-black">Don't have an account?</p>
                <a href="/auth"><p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-sm text-primary ml-1">Create one!</p></a>
            </div>
            </div>

        </>,
        <>
            <div>
                <div className="flex inline-block ">
                    <img src={require("../images/Logo.jpg")} alt="logo" className=" w-12 h-12 mb-4" />
                    <h1 className="text-primary font-CreteRoundRegular text-4xl ml-2 mt-1 ">TEST</h1>
                </div>

                <div className="flex flex-col mr-auto w-full">
                    <p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-xl text-primary mt-2">Enter password</p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your password" className="border-b-2 py-2 w-full border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-500 mb-4 mt-2" />
                </div>

                <div className="flex inline-block">
                    <p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-sm text-black">Forgot password?</p>
                    <a href="/auth"><p className="font-CreteRoundRegular text-sm text-primary ml-1">Reset password</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    ];
    

  return (
    <section className="flex h-screen bg-primary items-center justify-center">

        <div id="outerlayer" className="flex flex-col mobile:w-9/12 tablet:w-3/12 mobile:mb-32 tablet:mb-0 rounded-2xl w-full h-auto bg-white shadow-black shadow-md p-10 overflow-hidden relative">

        
        // fade in animation style
        <div id="layer" className="flex flex-col">

            <motion.div className="ease-in-out duration-500 transition-all" style={{transform: `translateX(-${count * 150}%)`}}>
                {
                    pageComponents[count]
                }
            </motion.div>

        </div>
        

        {count > 0 ?
            <div className="flex inline-block">
                <button id="previous" className="mt-10 mr-auto bg-primary text-white font-CreteRoundRegular px-5 py-2 rounded-full hover:bg-green-800" onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Previous</button> 
                <button id="signin" className="mt-10 ml-auto bg-primary text-white font-CreteRoundRegular px-5 py-2 rounded-full hover:bg-green-800" onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Sign in</button> 
            </div>
             : null}
            {count < pageComponents.length - 1 ? <button id="next" className="mt-10 ml-auto bg-primary text-white font-CreteRoundRegular px-5 py-2 rounded-full hover:bg-green-800" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Next</button> : null}


        </div>

    </section>
  )
}

export default Auth
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you need to add a transform property value inside the `motion.div` for the password input field.

```js
<motion.div className="ease-in-out duration-500 transition-all" style={{ transform: `translateX(${(1 - count) * 100}%)` }}>
    {pageComponents[count]}
</motion.div>
```

Comment: Doesn’t it already have this? How would I go about doing this?